# Netplan order of yaml?

Tags: networking, network-manager, netplan

I am testing out a netplan implementation for an IoT device, and I have a user config for wireless and a fall back config if the user one is invalid or not created yet.

I know that the last alphabetical file will addend/replace keys in the previous netplan which I am trying to take advantage of but I am not having any success.

Am I wrong in thinking that the 60-default's "wifis" key should completely replace 10-client's "wifis" key?

Here are my two netplans:

**10-client.yaml**

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    wifis:
     wlan0:
        dhcp4: true
        access-points:
          "SSID_NAME":
            password: "SSID_PASSWORD"
```

**60-default.yaml**

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
    wifis:
     wlan0:
        access-points:
          "IRIS-Incuvers-AP":
            mode: ap
```